# How do I get to the 13th Colossus?

Tags: shadow-of-the-colossus

This is somewhat embarrassing, but I'm unable to find my way to the 13th colossus. My sword leads me into a forest, but this appears to be a dead end.

How do I reach the 13th Colossus from the main temple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in a forest, but in the large desert (for which you have to travel a long way around). I think [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8V162NpHgM) should show you the way, if you don't mind watching it (just turn it off as soon as the colossus cutscene starts, to avoid spoilers).

Answer (score 0):

I found this [description for colossus 13](http://selmiak.bplaced.net/games/ps2/index.php?game=sotc&page=Solution-Colossus-13) very useful. There is even a map linked if nothing else works

Comment: Generally it's good practice to put some of the core content from the link into your answer, otherwise if the link changes your answer will be incorrect.